# weighted average based on a variable window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take a weighted average of "cycle" based on a "day" as window. The window is not always the same. How do I compute weighted average in pandas?

```
In [3]: data = {'cycle':[34.1, 41, 49.0, 53.9, 35.8, 49.3, 38.6, 51.2, 44.8],
'day':[6,6,6,13,13,20,20,20,20]}


In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=np.arange(9), columns = ['cycle', 'day'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   cycle  day
0   34.1    6
1   41.0    6
2   49.0    6
3   53.9   13
4   35.8   13
5   49.3   20
6   38.6   20
7   51.2   20
8   44.8   20
```

I would expect three values (if I have done this correctly):

34.1 * 1/3 + 41 * 1/3 + 49 * 1/3 = 41.36

```
cycle      day
41.36       6
 6.90      13
45.90      20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you just want:

```
df.groupby(['day']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Group on day, and then apply a lambda function that calculates the sum of the group and divides it by then number of non-null values within the group.

```
>>> df.groupby('day').cycle.apply(lambda group: group.sum() / group.count())
day
6     41.366667
13    44.850000
20    45.975000
Name: cycle, dtype: float64
```

Although you say weighted average, I don't believe there are any weights involved.  It appears as a simple average of the `cycle` value for a particular day.  In fact, a simple mean should suffice.

Also, I believe the value for day 13 should be calculated as `53.9 * 1/2 + 35.8 * 1/2` which yields 44.85.  Same approach for day 20.

Comment: Actually, that is correct, it's just the mean. I actually wanted to compute weighted average by day. That was my original question. The example was incorrect. How would that work? Thanks!

Comment: Give SQLnoob a bone.  His (Her?) answer is correct.

Comment: so should I ask another question?

Comment: I would give SQLnoob credit for this question, and then post another one including months in your example.

Comment: Perhaps I screwed up in asking. I wanted to compute weighted average by day and then take the mean by month. But I forgot to add month in the example. Does this warrant a new question or can I edit this one?